# Could graviton exist in a single polarisation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, polarization, chirality, twistor

Penrose's twistor theory can only construct a left-handed graviton. This is seen as a problem.

But... is there anything wrong with gravitons existing in only one polarisation?

How would gravity differ if this were the case.

For example, would it affect photons of different polarisations differently as they are bent by a star?

Would it effect the angular momentum of black holes?

Since we have never seen a graviton, we have no idea if they appear in more than one polarisation like the photon.

Presumably we would not be able to construct GR with only one polarisation of gravitons. But perhaps, if we abandon the right-handed part of GR and keep only the left-handed part, this might still predict all the gravitational effects we know yet may solve some other problems that Twistor theory sets out to solve.

So, is left-handed gravitation consistent with observation?

Comment: How do you plan to reduce the number of degrees of freedom in gravitons from the 10 in $h_{\mu \nu}$ to precisely 1? After gauge-fixing, and residual gauge-fixing, you remove 4+4=8 dofs, to finally get 10-8=2 dofs. How can you remove the remaining one dof?

Comment: @Avantgarde Probably in a similar way you would restrict the 4-vector for electromagnetism to a single polarised equation. I don't know the details myself. Because gravity is self-interacting it may be harder or impossible. IDK. e.g. could a left-handed graviton emit a right-handed graviton?

Comment: How can you restrict $A_\mu$ to have only 1 dof? After gauge and residual gauge-fixing, you are left with 4-2=2 dofs. How do you remove the other one? Also, a left-handed graviton emitting a right-handed graviton would violate angular momentum conservation, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is rhetorical or if you're really asking me? Of course you could have a Universe which exists of only left-handed photons and nothing else. You could  write an equation for it and eliminate the right-handed photons as unphysical. I don't know the equations.

Comment: I'm asking you. How do you "eliminate" right-handed photons, and regard the others as "unphysical"? What is the procedure? What makes the other photons unphysical? In principle, you still have 2 dofs. I don't see how you can remove the 1 dof, in principle.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know the math. But there is nothing in principle wrong with having a universe with only right-handed photons. Any more than having a universe with only left-handed neutrinos. As long as they are massless. As far as I know. I could be wrong though. (I probably am!)

Answer (score 2):

Recent observations at LIGO ([GW170814](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.141101) disfavour all non-standard assumptions for polarizations of gravitational wave, i.e. the observational data so far fits best to the standard concept of two ("plus" and "cross") possible polarizations.

Comment: When viewed "face on" or "face off" the waveform from merger is almost entirely circularly polarized. It is not clear you could distinguish there only being one handness to the polarization from normal GR in that case.

Comment: Interesting. So LIGO will be able to measure how many polarisations of gravitons there are?

Comment: @zooby LIGO alone wouldn’t, but the larger network of detectors including Virgo and KAGRA would ( to some degree)

Answer (score 1):

Penrose's Non-linear graviton construction works for a complex Riemannian Manifold (dim - 4). Here, one deforms a twistor space (or its dual space) to produce anti self dual (resp. self dual) parts of Weyl curvature which satisfy source free graviton equation. However, we live in a real Lorentzian manifold so both left handed and right handed gravitons are complex conjugates of one another, one cannot exist without the other. To understand the individual impacts of a.s.d. and s.d. part of curvature, we would need to know how different spinor fields couples with these curvature components in a curved space-time, I guess spinor fields which are either left handed or right handed can be differentially influenced. So we would need chiral fields to understand chiral nature of gravity. Besides, polarization of gravitational waves and duality of complex weyl curvatures (as constructed using Twistors) are two different things.

In Palatial Twistor approach, one can construct a general source free Weyl curvature which can be restricted to a real Lorentzian manifold. The non-linear graviton construction forms the building block for palatial twistor approach.

Comment: What's your opinion on 'palatial twistor theory'? It seems almost like a band-aid to fix up Twistor theory. I would like to understand it but Twistor theory is hard enough to get your head round!

Comment: The formal idea of Palatial Twistors seems quite natural, here you need to deform both PT and PT* to create asd and sd curvatures...and then you need to make an identification b/w them : the 2-form $\Sigma=dZ^{\alpha}\wedge dW_{\alpha}$ and the 2-form $\Theta=I_{\alpha\beta}dZ^{\alpha}\wedge dZ^{\beta}+I^{\alpha\beta}dW_{\alpha}\wedge dW_{\beta}$ both must be invariant under deformation. It's not clear why $\Sigma$ should be invariant (but I have two hpothesis regarding this assumption). Besides, I don't know how much of the Palatial twistor method has been accepted within twistor community